# Building a "hello, world!" program using MPW

Tags: programming, apple-macintosh, mac-os-classic

I've been setting up a Basilisk II emulator to try my hand at developing apps for 68k System 7 systems, and have set up the Macintosh Programmer's Workstation (v.3.5 Gold Master from MacintoshRepository.org). I wrote up a standard `hello.c` program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    printf("hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

After compiling with `SC hello.c`, I got a file `hello.c.o`, but when I tried executing the program, it tells me that "file hello.c.o is not executable".

I figured to try linking it with `link`, but am still getting an error:

```
### link: Error: Main code (-m option) name not found. (Error 53) %__MAIN
### link: Error: No Main code module or entry point. (Error 38)
### link: Errors prevented normal completion.
```

What to do? Am I missing a step?

Comment: You should add link option -t 'MPST' to create a command line tool rather than an application (which would need to initialize the GUI Toolbox etc). And -m 'main' will set the main entry point.

Comment: Got this error message, Mr Hugh Fisher

### LINK: Error: Undefined entry, name: (Error 28) "printf"
  Referenced from: main in file: hello.c.o
### LINK: Errors prevented normal completion.

Comment: As a general observation, if you want to use a runtime library you need to link with the runtime library. How that is done in your case I don't know. Maybe `-lc` ?

Comment: Right, but while I'm very familiar with GCC and clang I'm new to the compiler shipped with MPW and thus also its options for linking.

Comment: @AaravGarg I'm picking here the comment you made to PoC answer: “I'm new to this space and do not have access to such resources.” So, you want to develop on an environment you don't know,  you don't have any documentation upon, and you don't have (as you're running an emulator). May I ask you why you would want to do so, and what you would want to achieve? Not to be disdainful, just really interested in your answer.

Comment: Currently using an emulator, but waiting on my Color Classic to be delivered in a few weeks. I am a modern macOS developer and have an interest in how macOS development used to be long ago. I have _some_ experience in developing for classic OSs, but none for Mac OS Classic and want to learn.

Any documentation would be appreciated.

Comment: You may already be aware, @AaravGarg, but MacOS classic is not an older version of modern MacOS.  The two are completely different operating systems. Modern MacOS is the current form of the BSD-derived OS that Apple originally called "Mac OS X".  What is now called MacOS classic was an all-Apple-developed OS emerging from the company's line of previous OS's, the immediate predecessor being Lisa OS.

Comment: @HughFisher - you should post your comment as an answer (and maybe expand upon it a little). Comments are ephemeral in nature and tend to get deleted over time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### TL;DR

It is perfectly possible to run command line tools (that use `stdio.h`), on a Macintosh, but only ***from within MPW***.

For MPW 3.2.3

```
C hello.c
Link -d -c 'MPS ' -t MPST hello.c.o "{CLibraries}"StdClib.o "{Libraries}"Stubs.o "{Libraries}"Runtime.o "{Libraries}"Interface.o -o helloapp
helloapp
hello, world!
```

For MPW 3.5

```
SC hello.c
Link -d -c 'MPS ' -t MPST hello.c.o "{CLibraries}"StdClib.o "{Libraries}"Stubs.o "{Libraries}"MacRuntime.o "{Libraries}"Interface.o "{Libraries}"IntEnv.o  -o helloapp
helloapp
hello, world!
```

Note that it is safer (and simpler) to use the Build menu tools, provided by the UI:

- **Build** ► **Create Build Commands...**
- **Build** ► **Build...**

---

#### A useful thread

You *might* find the following useful.

From [post#5](https://68kmla.org/bb/index.php?threads/hello-world-in-c-on-os-6-0-8-in-mpw-3-1.6436/#post-74847) on [hello world in C on OS 6.0.8 in MPW 3.1](https://68kmla.org/bb/index.php?threads/hello-world-in-c-on-os-6-0-8-in-mpw-3-1.6436/), where someone was having the same issue as you (although this issue was on System 6 rather than System 7):

> ```
> link -d -c 'MPS ' -t MPST ∂
> hello.c.o ∂
> "{CLibraries}"StdClib.o ∂
> "{Libraries}"Stubs.o ∂
> "{Libraries}"Runtime.o ∂
> "{Libraries}"Interface.o ∂
> -o helloapp
> ```

where `∂` is <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

This same post goes on to say:

> Or, you could just select Create Make Commands... from the build menu, and fill out the dialog, selecting source files, target architecture, etc.  -c and -t set the file type and creator.  Single quotes on 'MPS ' are required because this is M P S space.  The libraries are what you need for a tool.  When getting started, Create Make Commands is preferred over doing it yourself because it knows what libraries you need to link.

The following [post#8](https://68kmla.org/bb/index.php?threads/hello-world-in-c-on-os-6-0-8-in-mpw-3-1.6436/#post-75213) states:

> Yes, the option-d is the continuation character.
>
> Your original error is caused by not linking with Runtime.o.  That is where %__MAIN (the entry point) is defined. Did you select the entire thing (all the lines containing the commands to build the program), and then type enter to execute the entire thing?   If so, I worry that there might be something wrong with your Runtime.o file.  Could it have become corrupted somehow?
>
> If you double click a tool in the Tools Directory, it will only launch MPW.  To run make, you don't double click it, but rather type its name in the shell, Unix style.  Anyway, you never even need to run Make that way.  You can go to the Build menu and select Build... or Show Build Commands....  Build will run Make and build your program.  Show Build Commands... will write the lines of shell script needed to build your program.  You then select the entire set of lines, and hit enter.  Try selecting Build... from the Build menu and see if MPW can build your program.

FWIW, The author of these two posts, basalgangster, has written extensively on [macgui.com](https://macgui.com/).

---

##### Error reproduction in MPW 3.5

[I have reproduced your errors](https://gr33nonline.wordpress.com/2024/03/30/building-a-hello-world-program-using-mpw-reproduction-steps/), and yes `Runtime.o` *is* missing. The linked thread also states (in [post#9](https://68kmla.org/bb/index.php?threads/hello-world-in-c-on-os-6-0-8-in-mpw-3-1.6436/post-75226)) that the MPW collection from Macintosh Garden is also missing `Runtime.o`:

```
link -d -c 'MPS ' -t MPST hello.c.o "{CLibraries}"StdClib.o "{Libraries}"Stubs.o "{Libraries}"Runtime.o "{Libraries}"Interface.o -o helloapp

### link: File not found (OS error -43)  
### link: Error: Can't open object file for input. (Error 32) Macintosh HD:MPW-GM:MPW::Interfaces&Libraries:Libraries:Libraries:Runtime.o
### link: Errors prevented normal completion.
```

[image: Screenshot of errors]

If you follow the path (`MPW-GM:MPW::Interfaces&Libraries:Libraries:Libraries`), you will see that `Runtime.o` isn't there, but `MacRuntime.o` *is* (due to changes made to MPW circa version 3.4/3.5). If you use `MacRuntime.o` instead, then you get a bit further, but with a different set of errors

```
link -d -c 'MPS ' -t MPST hello.c.o "{CLibraries}"StdClib.o "{Libraries}"Stubs.o "{Libraries}"MacRuntime.o "{Libraries}"Interface.o -o helloapp
### link: Error: Undefined entry, name: (Error 28) "_iob"
  Referenced from: printf in file: Macintosh HD:MPW-GM:MPW::Interfaces&Libraries:Libraries:CLibraries:StdClib.o
### link: Error: Undefined entry, name: (Error 28) "_flsbuf"
  Referenced from: _doprnt in file: Macintosh HD:MPW-GM:MPW::Interfaces&Libraries:Libraries:CLibraries:StdClib.o
### link: Error: Undefined entry, name: (Error 28) "_wrtchk"
  Referenced from: fwrite in file: Macintosh HD:MPW-GM:MPW::Interfaces&Libraries:Libraries:CLibraries:StdClib.o
### link: Error: Undefined entry, name: (Error 28) "write"
  Referenced from: fwrite in file: Macintosh HD:MPW-GM:MPW::Interfaces&Libraries:Libraries:CLibraries:StdClib.o
### link: Error: Undefined entry, name: (Error 28) "errno"
  Referenced from: fwrite in file: Macintosh HD:MPW-GM:MPW::Interfaces&Libraries:Libraries:CLibraries:StdClib.o
### link: Error: Undefined entry, name: (Error 28) "MacOSErr"
  Referenced from: fwrite in file: Macintosh HD:MPW-GM:MPW::Interfaces&Libraries:Libraries:CLibraries:StdClib.o
### link: Error: Undefined entry, name: (Error 28) "_xflsbuf"
  Referenced from: fwrite in file: Macintosh HD:MPW-GM:MPW::Interfaces&Libraries:Libraries:CLibraries:StdClib.o
### link: Error: Undefined entry, name: (Error 28) "_bufsync"
  Referenced from: fwrite in file: Macintosh HD:MPW-GM:MPW::Interfaces&Libraries:Libraries:CLibraries:StdClib.o
### link: Errors prevented normal completion.
```

To fix these errors you need to also include `IntEnv.o` (see below).

#### Further notes

##### For MPW v3.2.3

If you use MPW 3.2.3, again from Macintosh Repository ([MPW_1.0_3.1_3.2_and_68k_Developer_Kit.zip](https://www.macintoshrepository.org/download.php?id=2186)), then the commands (from [the thread linked to above](https://68kmla.org/bb/index.php?threads/hello-world-in-c-on-os-6-0-8-in-mpw-3-1.6436/)) work fine.

```
C hello.c
link -d -c 'MPS ' -t MPST hello.c.o "{CLibraries}"StdClib.o "{Libraries}"Stubs.o "{Libraries}"Runtime.o "{Libraries}"Interface.o -o helloapp
```

Here is a screen shot, showing the hello world code compiling, linking and running, *from within MPW 3.2.3*:

[image: Screenshot of success in MPW 3.2.3]

In text form:

```
C hello.c
Link -d -c 'MPS ' -t MPST hello.c.o "{CLibraries}"StdClib.o "{Libraries}"Stubs.o "{Libraries}"Runtime.o "{Libraries}"Interface.o -o helloapp
helloapp
hello, world!
```

##### For MPW 3.5

Changes made around MPW v3.4/3.5, mean that `Runtime.o` is now `MacRuntime.o` and you also have to include `IntEnv.o`:

```
SC hello.c -sym off -model near
Link -d -c 'MPS ' -t MPST hello.c.o "{CLibraries}"StdClib.o "{Libraries}"Stubs.o "{Libraries}"MacRuntime.o "{Libraries}"Interface.o "{Libraries}"IntEnv.o  -o helloapp
```

The `Link` command above is a *severely* pruned version of the command generated by the MPW **Build...** menu item:

```
ILink -o helloapp ":hello.c.o" "{Libraries}Stubs.o" "{Libraries}MathLib.o" "{CLibraries}StdCLib.o" "{Libraries}MacRuntime.o" "{Libraries}IntEnv.o" "{Libraries}ToolLibs.o" "{Libraries}Interface.o" -sym off -mf -d -t 'MPST' -c 'MPS ' -model near -state rewrite -compact -pad 0
```

Here is a screen shot, showing the hello world code compiling, linking and running, *from within MPW 3.5*:

[image: Screenshot of success in MPW 3.5]

In text form:

```
SC hello.c
Link -d -c 'MPS ' -t MPST hello.c.o "{CLibraries}"StdClib.o "{Libraries}"Stubs.o "{Libraries}"MacRuntime.o "{Libraries}"Interface.o "{Libraries}"IntEnv.o  -o helloapp
helloapp
hello, world!
```

#### Summary

- Note that for both versions of MPW, there is *no* need to use the `-m 'main'` option - that is a red herring from your original linker error.
- The main issue why the commands from [the thread](https://68kmla.org/bb/index.php?threads/hello-world-in-c-on-os-6-0-8-in-mpw-3-1.6436/) do not work in MPW 3.5 is that:

  - MPW version 3.5 does *not* have the file

    ```
    Libraries:Libraries:Runtime.o
    ```

    whereas version 3.2.3 *does*. MPW 3.5 has `MacRuntime.o` instead.
  - MPW 3.5 also requires that you include

    ```
    "{Libraries}"IntEnv.o
    ```
- You can not double click the application, or rather, the "MPW tool" - for obvious reasons (there is no standard IO) - you have to run `helloapp` *from within MPW environment*.
- MPW 3.2.3 uses `C`, whereas MPW 3.5 uses either `SC` (Symantec C) for 68k, or `MrC` for PowerPC - see [this answer](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/2318/202) to [Building hello world on a Macintosh IIfx with MPW](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1326/202) for more details.
- If you want to see the full story, please read [Building a “hello, world!” program using MPW – Reproduction steps](https://gr33nonline.wordpress.com/2024/03/30/building-a-hello-world-program-using-mpw-reproduction-steps/).

#### Documentation

You can find a wealth of documentation on [vintageapple.org](https://vintageapple.org/).

*Inside Macintosh*:

- [Inside Macintosh Series - original version](https://vintageapple.org/inside_o/)
- [Inside Macintosh Series - revamped version](https://vintageapple.org/inside_r/)

*MPW*:

- [MPW and Assembly Language Programming for the Macintosh (1987)](https://vintageapple.org/macprogramming/pdf/MPW_and_Assembly_Language_Programming_for_the_Macintosh_1987.pdf)
- [Programmers Guide to MPW (1990)](https://vintageapple.org/macprogramming/pdf/Programmers_Guide_to_MPW_1990.pdf)

An assortment of programming guides:

- [Vintage Macintosh Programming Book Library](https://vintageapple.org/macprogramming/)

Comment: By the way, the first code snippet didn't work; Runtime.o is not a thing? But the Create Build Commands step worked like a charm!

Comment: In the makefile generated by Create Build, these are the libraries specified.

LibFiles-68K    =  ∂
      "{Libraries}MathLib.o" ∂
      "{CLibraries}StdCLib.o" ∂
      "{Libraries}SIOW.o" ∂
      "{Libraries}MacRuntime.o" ∂
      "{Libraries}IntEnv.o" ∂
      "{Libraries}ToolLibs.o" ∂
      "{Libraries}Interface.o"

Answer (score 4):

Classic MacOS has no concept of stdin/stdout compared to POSIX conformant platforms. See the comment of Hugh Fisher for a workaround.

It might be beneficial to read the initial Inside Macintosh books for general ideas how to program applications for the older MacOS environment.

Comment: But command-line programs are supported? Mr. Fisher's comment was helpful but gave an error message as I have posted above. While I'd love to read the Inside Macintosh books, I'm afraid I'm new to this space and do not have access to such resources.

Comment: @AaravGarg Inside Macintosh is basically the classic Mac OS Apple equivalent to the MSDN library. While I don't personally know whether Apple ever offered a downloadable version on their website, I know they did make tons of digital releases of it over the years. (eg. At least one of the monthly Apple Developer CDs would include it each year... probably more before they needed to split off the QuickDraw GX stuff and put it on a different month's CD.)

Comment: MPW acts as a command shell, which can run programs that interact with stdin, stdout, and stderr, and can make them interact with the Workspace, or redirect them using less-than (stdin), greater-than (stdout), greater-than-or-equal (stderr), or uppercase sigma (both stdout and stderr).

Comment: As an aside, with the Aztec C development kit for the Macintosh, this would have "just worked". They provided a more conventional command line style development environment with a shell, and vi as the editor. Very basic UNIX-like environment. But it was designed to create Mac applications.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question. The link step has failed because there's no `__MAIN` symbol defined. I wonder if `-m` allows you to specify a `main` function

Comment: @WillHartung: MPW is rather Unix-like.  By default, program output behaves as though typed in a text window called the "workspace", and pushing the keypad enter on a line will feed that line to stdin.  The command "file" opens a file in a document window if not already open and selects that window; "line" moves to the appropriate line.  The message for a compilation error in line 123 of `foo.c` would start with `file "foo.c"; line 123 #`, allowing a programmer to hit enter on that line to go to the error location.

Comment: It is best to quote the comment of Hugh Fisher as comments are ephemeral in nature and tend to be deleted over time. Answers should try to be self-contained.

Comment: Command line programs are NOT supported by Classic MacOS. Decision in the early design process for the Mac so that people wouldn't just port existing CLI software. (This is also why the first Mac keyboard had no arrow or function keys.) You can sort of write a CLI program, but first you have to write a GUI terminal emulator for it to run inside.

MPW exists because developing software without an IDE wasn't common at the time, so Apple re-invented Unix to make programmers more productive.

Comment: @JeremyP -  there is no need to use the `-m` option, see my answer